# Is there a way to optimize the calculation of Bernoulli Log-Likelihoods for many multivariate samples?

Tags: math, pytorch, log-likelihood

I currently have two Torch Tensors, `p` and `x`, which both have the shape of `(batch_size, input_size)`.

I would like to calculate the Bernoulli log likelihoods for the given data, and return a tensor of size `(batch_size)`

Here's an example of what I'd like to do:
I have the formula for log likelihoods of Bernoulli Random variables:

`\sum_i^d x_{i} ln(p_i) + (1-x_i) ln (1-p_i)`

Say I have `p` Tensor:
`[[0.6 0.4 0], [0.33 0.34 0.33]]`
And say I have the `x` tensor for the binary inputs based on those probabilities:

`[[1 1 0], [0 1 1]]`

And I want to calculate the log likelihood for every sample, which would result in:

`[[ln(0.6)+ln(0.4)], [ln(0.67)+ln(0.34)+ln(0.33)]]`

Would it be possible to do this computation without the use of for loops?
I know I could use `torch.sum(axis=1)` to do the final summation between the logs, but is it possible to do the Bernoulli log-likelihood computation without the use of for loops? or use at most 1 for loop? I am trying to vectorize this operation as much as possible. I could've sworn we could use LaTeX for equations before, did something change or is it another website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not a good practice, you can directly use the formula on the tensors as follows (works because these are element wise operations):

```py
import torch
p = torch.tensor([
    [0.6, 0.4, 0],
    [0.33, 0.34, 0.33]
])

x = torch.tensor([
    [1., 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1]
])

eps = 1e-8
bll1 = (x * torch.log(p+eps) + (1-x) * torch.log(1-p+eps)).sum(axis=1)
print(bll1)
#tensor([-1.4271162748, -2.5879497528])
```

Note that to avoid `log(0)` error, I have introduced a very small constant `eps` inside it.

A better way to do this is to use [BCELoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html) inside `nn` module in `pytorch`.

```py
import torch.nn as nn
bce = nn.BCELoss(reduction='none')
bll2 = -bce(p, x).sum(axis=1)
print(bll2)
#tensor([-1.4271162748, -2.5879497528])
```

Since `pytorch` computes the BCE as a *loss*, it prepends your formula with a negative sign. The attribute `reduction='none'` says that I do not want the computed losses to be reduced (averaged/summed) across the batch in any way. This is advisable to use since we do not need to manually take care of numerical stability and error handling (such as adding `eps` above.)

You can indeed verify that the two solutions actually return the same tensor (upto a tolerance):

```py
torch.allclose(bll1, bll2)
# True
```

or the tensors (without summing each row):

```py
torch.allclose((x * torch.log(p+eps) + (1-x) * torch.log(1-p+eps)), -bce(p, x))
# True
```

Feel free to ask for further clarifications.